# Setting gzip from .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, gzip

I have a wordpress blog stuck on a cheap shared host at the moment.

I am trying to setup gzip compression from the .htaccess file, I have tried this...

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

But that does not seem to work.

Now if I set it from my a PHP file like this...

```
if(extension_loaded("zlib") && (ini_get("output_handler") != "ob_gzhandler"))
   add_action('wp', create_function('', '@ob_end_clean();@ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 1);'));
```

The PHP method successfully gzips my php pages, but I would prefer to do this from the .htaccess file so that I can automatically compress javascript and css files as well without running them through PHP.

---

**UPDATE**
After much testing, I believe possibly it does not work from my .htaccess because maybe the shared server does not have this enabled, so the only way to compress anything would be through PHP, bummer

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` to check whether `httpd.conf` could be overridden by `.htaccess` directives.